# Box and Whisker plot - dots over the box

Tags: data-visualization, boxplot

I have a box and whisker plot, and I am unable to understand the meaning of the dots over the box.

In the following example, I understand that outliers are the data points which do not "fit" inside the figure, so in the following figure, the outliers make sense -
[image]

Now , I came across a variation of a box plot -

[image]

where here, I am unable to make sense of the blue, yellow, and grey dots which are marked over the box as I think it should have been part of the box rather than being shown over the box. Any help/hint in the interpretation of these dots over the box would be very useful.

Comment: They're almost certainly data points. Where did you see this plot?

Comment: This is nonstandard. Either the author gives an explicit explanation what these points are, or they can't expect to be understood. We can guess at best.

Comment: I agree with @Glen_b that they're likely meant to be data points--but if so, then the boxes are incorrectly drawn!  Where are the medians, for instance?  Are they the crosses (no--you can confirm those are wrong in the yellow and gray boxes) or the midlines (no, they are clearly wrong in the blue and gray boxes).  The only way to reconcile the points and the boxes is to suppose there is some overplotting of points.  BTW, the whisker lengths in the sketch at the top are way too small: they should be about three times longer.

Comment: I had thought that it might be that data points that coincided with the plotting positions of the hinges, median and whiskers might have been omitted (or perhaps some of them at least) for some reason, but heavy overplotting may also be present. Whisker lengths may be quite short if there's no data points within the fences that are farther from the hinges.

Comment: @Glen_b About the whisker lengths: that's right--but I was referring to the first illustration, not the second.  The first shows individual data points that would lie well within the bounds of a properly-sized whisker.

Comment: Ah, my apologies.